# Postfix or mutt changes subject string

Tags: linux, postfix, mutt

I suspect that when I send a message to my postfix server with Re: in the beginning of the subject I get the following view in mutt:

[image]

The first message containg Re: looks fine. But if I resend exactly the same email it's transformed into a three character shortcut.

How to change that behavior so that the same subject name is not changed to └*> string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just how `mutt` displays mails that are on the same thread. It is intended to make it obvious at a glance which messages belong to the same discussion, and is really useful if you subscribe to mailing lists.

I am not aware of a way to alter this functionality, but if you open the message to read it in `mutt`'s pager, you will see that the Subject: header is displayed in full - `mutt` hasn't rewritten the Subject: header at all, but just displays it differently in the index view.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's just the way mutt shows mails with RE: in the beginning. I've actually asked this question, because I procmail incoming mails to do some jobs on them. I found out that when this *> character is displayed my .procmailrc is not working on them as inteded. But because you confirmed what I had suspected, I will have to look for error elsewhere. Thanks!